# How to send buffer to audio file in Supercollider?

Tags: audio, supercollider

I'm working on a simple Supercollider patch (my first), designed to swap samples in a file to get a stuttering, granular synthesis sort of sound.

What I'm trying to do is make a new audio file that's the length of the input file. It should run a loop that will swap the place of samples in a file with the sample at the scrambled indexes.

I haven't been able to find a way to get it to compile and write an audio file.

```
var indexa, indexb, frames, count, j, aa, ab;
j = 0;

s.boot;

b = Buffer.read(s, "/Users/admin/Desktop/10counter.aiff"); //my test file

"Frames: " + b.numFrames.postln;
"Channels: " + b.numChannels.postln;

count = b.numFrames * b.numChannels;

"Count: " + count.postln;

b.write("/Users/admin/Desktop/rbs.aiff", "aiff", "int16", 0, 0, true);

opCount.do ({

    temp1 = Buffer.alloc(s, 1, 2);
    temp2 = Buffer.alloc(s, 1, 2);

    aa = Array.fill(frames, {arg i; i});
    ab = a1.scramble;
})

//do the swaps
{j < count}.while ({

    indexa = aa[j];
    indexb = ab[j];

    temp1 = b.get(indexa);
    temp2 = b.get(indexb);

    b.set(indexb, temp1);
    b.set(indexa, temp2);

    j.increment;
})

//write to file here?

b.close;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just need the [Buffer.write](http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/Buffer.html#-write) method. Put it at the bottom of the code, like you suggest. I'm not sure what the existing `b.write` is supposed to be doing - you've presumably copied it from somewhere but it's not needed, you don't want to write the file before you've modified it, and also you don't want the `leaveOpen` argument to be `true` (because you're doing a single write, not continuously streaming to disk).

Comment: I get this message when I insert Buffer.write(////):  

`ERROR: Command line parse failed
nil
ERROR: syntax error, unexpected CLASSNAME, expecting $end
  in file 'selected text'
  line 44 char 6:

  Buffer.write("/Users/admin/Desktop/rbs.aiff", "aiff", "int16", -1, 0, false);
  ^^^^^^`  
and this message when I use the declared buffer, b:  
`ERROR: Command line parse failed
nil
ERROR: syntax error, unexpected NAME, expecting $end
  in file 'selected text'
  line 44 char 1:

  b.write("/Users/admin/Desktop/rbs.aiff", "aiff", "int16", -1, 0, false);
  ^`

Comment: (1) indeed you do need to execute `b.write(...)` where `b` is the `Buffer` you created earlier on. (2) you've got a syntax error, and it's probably because you forgot a semicolon on the line before the line you tried. If you see the phrase "syntax error" then you have a syntax error, i.e. you've made a typing mistake which is preventing the code from even running